# Conditional CSS: if sibling's child div is present, then

Tags: css

In the html fragment below, I want the "main" div to have a background image only if "menu" div is not present in the markup. Is this possible?

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="siteTitle">site title</div>
    <div class="tagline">site tagline</div>
    <div class='menu'></div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS selector for this. Your choices are putting classes on a parent element of main or using JavaScript.

Comment: If there is only a single header and single main you should use an id instead of a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

> E + F Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.
>   E:not(s)  an E element that does not match simple selector s

**edit** `:not` uses a simple selector, so unfortunately you can't use it to filter by properties of children, only attributes of the element.

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

You could however put a .empty class on the menu and still use it.

```
.header .menu:not(.empty) + .main {
   background:pink;
}
```

This solution is the best of both worlds, javascript but using css as per normal.

javascript:

```
if ($('.menu').length == 0){
    $('body').addClass('no_menu');
}
```

css :

```
body.no_menu .main{
    background:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only pure css solution i see is only possible if you rearrange your html like so:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="siteTitle">site title</div>
    <div class="tagline">site tagline</div>
</div>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

then you can use this css to only apply a property):

```
.menu { background: none }
.menu ~ .main{ background: url() } /* or .menu + .main if they are guaranteed to be adjacent to each other on the code */
```

in this example, you can see it at work: http://jsfiddle.net/tYhxr/ 

(test it by deleting the menu div and running it again)

check [Keyo's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342760/conditional-css-if-siblings-child-div-is-present-then/4342981#4342981) for a link about how selectors work.

If you can't change the html, the javascript is the way to go.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second class to your main `<div>` that only serves to add the background you want. Then when you create the markup, you just add the second class specifier to the `<div>` if you need it, or omit it if you don't.

```
div.main {
  //main stuff
}

div.mainbg {
  background: *background-specifications*;
}
```

When your menu div is present, you use this:

```
<div class="main mainbg">
```

And when it's missing, you stick with:

```
<div class="main">
```